# How do I make table text smaller if a mobile user is detected?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My JS:

```js
window.onload = function(){
    if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|Windows Phone/i.test(this.navigator.userAgent)){
        document.getElementById('datatable').style.fontSize = "10px";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('datatable').style.fontSize = "20px";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<table class="TFtable" id="datatable">
  ...
</table>
```

Please note: there are currently no styles to do with font-size which are affecting class 'TFtable'.

Comment: Why are you not working with media queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS media queries to target devices with a viewport of less than 600px.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table.TFtable {
    font-size: /* your smaller font size*/;
  }
}
```

Comment: Finally - A proper answer

Answer (score 0):

From a excelent answer [Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser), here is the solution.

```
if (typeof window.orientation !== 'undefined') {
    document.getElementById('datatable').style.fontSize = "10px";
}else {
    document.getElementById('datatable').style.fontSize = "20px";
}
```

as you requested for iPhone only,

here is what you can do

```
var iOS = !!navigator.platform && /iPhone/.test(navigator.platform);
```

use this iOS variable, iOS will be a boolean.

Comment: but keep one thing on mind that this will happy all the mobile and iPad as well, every device which use orientation

Comment: is there a way of detecting just iPhones?

Comment: if the requirement is to change font only  on mobile devices, then CSS option is the best as  answered by kaleidawave, it will work all the devices, but if you want to do something with iPhone only then that will not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(window).width() < 900) {
   document.getElementById('datatable').style.fontSize = "10px";
}
else{
        document.getElementById('datatable').style.fontSize = "20px";

}
```